# How to derive analog of power rule for other forms of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

**Introduction**

We'll be dealing with multiple forms of calculus here. So we'll use $\operatorname{L_d}(f(x))$ to refer to the additive derivative, $\cfrac{df}{dx}$, $\operatorname{P_d}(f(x))$ to refer to the product derivative, and $\operatorname{H_d}(f(x))$ to refer to the harmonic derivative. These derivative satisfy certain properties that make them useful for approximating particular functions.

(Skip to the bottom for the question)

**Background**

$$(1) \quad \operatorname{L_d}(f(x)+g(x))=\operatorname{L_d}(f(x))+\operatorname{L_d}(g(x))$$
$$(2) \quad \operatorname{P_d}(f(x) \cdot g(x))=\operatorname{P_d}(f(x))\cdot \operatorname{P_d}(g(x))$$
$$(3) \quad \operatorname{H_d}\left(\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{f(x)}+\cfrac{1}{g(x)}}\right)=\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\operatorname{H_d}(f(x))}+\cfrac{1}{\operatorname{H_d}(g(x))}}$$

For a general derivative, with an associated mapping $F$, we have,

$$(4) \quad \operatorname{F_d}(f(x))=\lim_{{\epsilon} \to 0} \ F^{-1} \left( \cfrac{1}{\epsilon} \cdot \left(F(f(x+\epsilon))-F(f(x))\right)\right)$$

Using $F(x)=x$, $\ F(x)=\log(x)$, and $\ F(x)=\cfrac{1}{x}$ gives the Linear, Product, and Harmonic derivatives respectively. Given a nice $F$, the "F" derivative satisfies,

$$(5) \quad \operatorname{F_d}\left( F^{-1} \left( F(f(x))+F(g(x)) \right) \right)=F^{-1} \cdot \left[ F( \operatorname{F_d}(f(x)) )+F(\operatorname{F_d}( g(x) )) \right]$$

Given all the above information, I'm interested in finding the generalized "F" Taylor series for function $f(x)$. In both the Linear and Product cases, we simply have to find a function $p(x)$ such that,

$$(6) \quad \operatorname{F_d}(p(x^n))=p(n \cdot x^{n-1})$$

Then we define $x^0=1$ and expand about a point $x_0$ using an ansatz,

$$(7) \quad f(x)=F^{-1} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F(p(a_n \cdot (x-x_0)^n)) \right)$$

Finally, we take the "F" derivative at $x=x_0$ and use $6$ to simplify.

**Question**

How does one find this function $p(x)$ that satisfies $(6)$, if you're given $F(x)$?

For a concrete example, I'm trying to find $p(x)$ for $F(x)=\cfrac{1}{x}$. I don't care about uniqueness or anything like that, I just want one example of a $p(x)$ that works. In general, I assume this is an impossible task.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding well, but doesn't $p(x) = F^{-1}(x)$ work in all cases?

Comment: @preguntun $F(x)=\cfrac{1}{x}$ has $p(x)=\cfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: Yes, and $F(x)=\sin(x)$ has $p(x)=\arcsin(x)$, $F(x)=e^x$ has $p(x) = \log(x)$, and so on, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Since $\mathrm{F_d}(p(x)) = F^{-1}(\frac{d}{dx}F(p(x)))$, taking $p(x)=F^{-1}(x)$ makes $\mathrm{F_d}(p(x^n)) = \mathrm{F_d}(F^{-1}(x^n))=F^{-1}(\frac{d}{dx}x^n)=F^{-1}(nx^{n-1})=p(nx^{n-1})$.

Comment: @pregunton If you look at my comment, on the answer, from the other question, you'll get my reaction to the whole thing ;)

Comment: Well, sometimes it's easy to miss simple solutions, especially when one is expecting a more complicated thing :)